# On image click redirect to other page and play the video

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages Recipe.aspx and RecipeVideo.aspx, On recipe page images will be displayed on each image click related video should be opened on RecipeVideo.aspx.

I tried this but it only Redirects to other page

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/images/food-trending-meal-pops-L-qw162R.jpeg" runat="server" Height="94px" Width="141px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />

 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/RecipeVideo.aspx");
        }
```

Please can any one give an idea how to do this.

Comment: Parameter passing with get and post is the one you want.  `Response.Redirect("~/RecipeVideo.aspx?id="+(sender).Tag.ToString());`

Comment: need to embed youtube video on image click

Comment: or you can pass the youtube url to the `RecipeVideo.aspx?url:youtubeurl`

Comment: Yes but need to embed the video

Comment: This is a typical coding in asp.net - I mean that you need to take some lessons and learn asp.net and web programming in general. Even if you solve that with an example, you need many more to know when you programming on web and you are not going anywhere with out lessons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be - 
Declare a global javascript variable like this

```
var videoSource= '';
```

It should be in an external js file outside all the functions and above all the below functions. Then  let your button be like

```
<input type ="submit" id = "image-button" onclick ="ShowVideo('pass the src value of the corresponding video as the parameter')"/>
```

Then add the show video method as

```
function ShowVideo(source){
    videoSource = source;
    window.location.assign('url of second page you want to load');
}
```

then on second page, you can do like this

```
<iframe style = "Display: None" id = "video" width="854" height="480" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script>
window.onload = SetVideo();
</script>
```

Add the method in the external js file

```
function SetVideo(){
    document.getElementById('video').src = videoSource;
}
```

Comment: On clicking image i need to redirect to other page, on that page the video should embed dynamically

Comment: @akileshkhoday Then you want that the video displayed should depend on the image that was clicked?? Is it

Comment: Yes exactly i need

Comment: @akileshkhoday check now